# How to set an expiry date for UNLocationNotificationTrigger

Tags: swift3, cllocation, unusernotificationcenter

I am setting a UNLocationNotificationTrigger to trigger at a specific location. I would like the notification to be displayed only if the user enters the location before a certain date. If he enters the location at a later date, the notification should not be triggered.

Is it possible to set an expiry date for a UNLocationNotificationTrigger?

Answer (score 0):

There is no expiry date for a Local Notification. To achieve your scenario, what you can do is schedule a timer some time before your checking date, to check if the user has entered the location or not. If he has, schedule the notification. If he hasn't don't schedule it. A timer can be scheduled like the following :

```
let timer = Timer(fire: your-date, interval: 0, repeats: false, block: {(timer: Timer) -> Void in
                // check for location and schedule accordingly
            })
RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```

Make sure that the date you set in the timer is a little earlier then your notification date, so that it gets time to schedule the notification and the notification gets displayed.

Hope this helps. :)